# Create 8 bit bitmap from array

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to create a bitmap from an array of pixels.

```
var height = 2;
var width = 2;
var output = new byte[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(output, GCHandleType.Pinned);

var stride = width * sizeof(byte);
var pointer = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, pointer))
{
}
```

However I get `System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'`, with no inner exception or further details.

I don't want to use `SetPixel` because my real array is very large.

This is using the `System.Drawing.Common 4.5.0` library for `.Net Standard 2.0`

Comment: You have to understand the bitmap format to get this right, 8bpp is painful due to its need for a palette and stride.  Just do it the other way around to make it easier, use new Bitmap(int, int, PixelFormat) and then LockBits to poke the values into it.  And do keep in mind that everybody and his brother gave up on 8bpp with a big sigh of relieve 20 years ago.  More than plenty of oomph available today to afford the much faster 32bpp.  Which lets you ignore palette and stride.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this maybe:

```
unsafe public static void Main()
{
   var height = 2;
   var width = 2;
   var output = new byte[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4};
   using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed))
   {
      var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
      Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, output, 0, 4);
      bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
      bitmap.Save(@"D:\blah.bmp");
   }
}
```

[Bitmap.LockBits Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Bitmap.LockBits Method

Locks a Bitmap into system memory.

[Marshal.Copy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Copies data from a managed array to an unmanaged memory pointer, or
> from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed array.

---

As noted just work in the 32bpp, and make your life easier

```
public static void Main()
{
   var height = 2;
   var width = 2;
   var c = Color.White.ToArgb();
   var output = new int[4] { c, c, c, c };
   using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed))
   {
      var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

      Marshal.Copy(output, 0, data.Scan0, 4);
      bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
      bitmap.Save(@"D:\trdy.bmp");
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use `Marshal.Copy`, the method does not need to be marked as unsafe. Do note that you have to copy line by line or the stride will be messed up, since the internals of an object in .Net will always have a stride divisible by 4 bytes.